# Using compiled resources in iPhone projects instead of source files

Tags: iphone, xcode

when I have to use third parties code (ex.: three20) I normally import the source code into my iPhone XCode project. Is there a way to import the compiled library (one file only) instead of importing all the source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static libraries. Youu can refer for example to this article (XCode 3.X):

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html

It explains not only how to use the library, but also how to make one by yourself.

Here is one (maybe better) which shows the same but in XCode 4:

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/#using_a_static_library